# Manually downloading and installing maven plugins

Tags: java, maven

**I am on proxy network and proxy is preventing maven to connect to central repo**

*Is there any way to download the maven plugins manually and installing the plugins in local .m2 repo.*

Thanks

Comment: Both Maven artifacts and plugins are downloaded over HTTP. How did you manage to reach SO?

Comment: do you build on some machine that has unblocked internet access, then just copy your .m2 to the machine that doesnt?

Comment: no .. i dont have machine that has access :(

Comment: In a corporate environment you really need to use a Maven repository and then connect all your Maven builds to it. Otherwise you're constantly fighting the network proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use any machine that can connect to central to download all repo you need then copy ./m2 manually to your machine with usage of offline flag every build

if your solution is scalable you will need to install nexus or any maven repository on machine can goes outside and you configure maven to see repo machine. and this is the model solution to that case

Answer (score 8):

If you have the jar, you can use :

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=<your_group_name>  \
-DartifactId=<your_artifact_name>  \
-Dversion=<version>  \
-Dfile=<path_to_your_jar_file>  \
-Dpackaging=jar \
-DgeneratePom=true
```

An example of the same:

```
mvn install:install-file  \
-DgroupId="org.apache.maven.plugins"  \
-DartifactId="maven-site-plugin"  \
-Dversion="3.7.1"  \
-Dfile="D:\Jars\maven-site-plugin-3.7.1.jar"  \
-Dpackaging=jar  \
-DgeneratePom=true
```

if you  don't have the (plug-in) jar, and it's not a private artefact, you can find the jar and the information in repository website (for example http://mvnrepository.com/ ) or download from your private repository like Nexus or Azure Feeds.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here if you want to configure a proxy for maven. That way you do not need to download the dependencies in any obscure and unreliable way: [Howto configure a proxy for Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)

Answer (score 0):

To install a jar you can use `install:install-file` to install any kind of jar. But a maven plugin comes with dependencies so you will have to install them. My suggestion would be to copy a .m2 repo from a machine with access to the internet (for maven).